# How to run function onclick? | Java script

Tags: javascript, onclick, buttonclick

Tries to write a script that finds rows in the table based on the searchbar and returns the result, but I got a problem with running function onclick. What am I doing wrong?

```js
 function tableToArray(myTable) {
  var result = []
  var rows = myTable.rows;
  var cells, t;

  // Iterate over rows
  for (var i=0, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    cells = rows[i].cells;
    t = [];

    // Iterate over cells
    for (var j=0, jLen=cells.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      t.push(cells[j].textContent);
    }
    result.push(t);
  }
  
  var programs = result.map(function(value,index) { return value[0]; }); 
  var search = document.getElementById('programInput').value.toUpperCase();
  var wynik = result.filter(function(item){return item[0] === search; });
   
 return wynik;
}
    
    document.write(JSON.stringify(tableToArray(document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0])));
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="programInput">
 <button id="programbutton" type="submit" onclick="tableToArray(myTable)">Search</button>
<div id="results">

</div>
<table id="myTable"  style="border: none;"><thead class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_thead" style="border:none; : 1px solid #ccc; "><tr class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_tr"><th class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_th " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:#fff; background-color:#fff; ">Program</th><th class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_th " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:#fff; background-color:#fff; ">Typ</th><th class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_th " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:#fff; background-color:#fff; ">Obsługiwany</th><th class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_th " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:#fff; background-color:#fff; ">Type</th></tr></thead><tbody class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_tbody"><tr class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_tr"><td class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_td " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:left; background-color:#fff; ">Program1</td><td class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_td " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:left; background-color:#fff; ">PP</td><td class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_td " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:left; background-color:#fff; ">TRUE</td><td class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_td " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:left; background-color:#fff; ">A</td></tr><tr class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_tr"><td class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_td " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:left; background-color:#fff; ">Program2</td><td class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_td " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:left; background-color:#fff; ">PP</td><td class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_td " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:left; background-color:#fff; ">FALSE</td><td class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_td " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:left; background-color:#fff; ">B</td></tr></tbody><tfoot class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_tfoot"><tr class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_tr"><td class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_td " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:left; background-color:#fff; ">Program3</td><td class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_td " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:left; background-color:#fff; ">PP</td><td class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_td " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:left; background-color:#fff; ">TRUE</td><td class="wp2s2fg_fetcher_table_td " style="font-size:16px; color:inherit; line-height:1; letter-spacing:1px; font-weight:normal; border:none; border: 1px solid #ccc; text-align:left; background-color:#fff; ">C</td></tr></tfoot></table>
```

Comment: `onclick="tableToArray(myTable)"` what is `myTable`?

Comment: @Rojo Id of Table

Answer (score 1):

you can not access rows like this myTable.rows as myTable is not a json object its a reference to table html element. You should use document.queryselectorall to get rows and columns inside table.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was a problem with onclick because when I ran the function manually it worked

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can pass a variable like that. I would use `querySelector` for the button and the table in the js script. Then add an event listener to the button.

I could be wrong, but I think that's your issue. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Glad you're here to help!  Please check this for guidelines on writing a good answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer